# Unable to mount usb drive

Tags: debian, mount, usb-flash-drive

I try to mount a usb key but it does not work.

`dmesg | grep SCSI`:

```
[    1.213907] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 253)
[    1.614532] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    3.344963] scsi4 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
[    8.364839] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

`fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/cciss/c0d0: 600.1 GB, 600093712384 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 72957 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0000a54e

           Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/cciss/c0d0p1   *           1       72044   578691072   83  Linux
/dev/cciss/c0d0p2           72044       72958     7334913    5  Extended
/dev/cciss/c0d0p5           72044       72958     7334912   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 009 Device 003: ID 03f0:1027 Hewlett-Packard Virtual keyboard and mouse
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0624:0341 Avocent Corp.
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0951:1607 Kingston Technology DataTraveler 100
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`fdisk -l /dev/sda` returns nothing.

The device seems to be detected but I cannot mount it :

`mount -t vfat /dev/sda /mnt`:

```
mount: no medium found on /dev/sda
```

On this usb drive, there is the bootable Debian image created with unetbootin.

Comment: The purpose is to mount this usb drive not to use unetbootin ;-) any idea ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with exactly what unetbootin does to create an image, I'm only familiar with lots of people having trouble using it with debian images.  Its however, no longer needed for creating bootable debian isos. The debian installer isos are now hybrid isos that can be copyied directly to a disk.  So in your case just

```
cp debian-whatver.iso /dev/sda
```

Would create a working, bootable usb drive.  Of course, please always make sure that /dev/sda is the correct drive before doing anything like this, as it will erase the contents of /dev/sda.